# 'My' or 'mine'?

Tags: word-choice, software, possessive-pronouns, possessive-determiners

We are making a piece of software that lists some kind of objects. An object may belong to a user (be 'private') or it may be made 'public'. The list is quite large, therefore in the list form there's a filter panel. One of the controls on that panel is the 'Privacy' drop-down box with three options: 'My only', 'My & public', 'All'.

However, this usage of a possessive determiner without a noun seems dubious to me. Wouldn't it be better to use 'mine' instead of 'my'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  *Mine*, as a pronoun ([m-w, usage 2](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mine)), should be used here.  *My* is an adjective ([m-w](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/my)) and requires a noun.

Comment: Nobody has concurred, so I accept.

Answer (score 2):

"Mine" is correct, but in this context, I would suggest using an alternative term such as "Personal"

Comment: We use the term 'private' (which is by now well established). However, just 'private' would mean 'anyone's private' and we want 'current user's private', only we also want it as concise as possible, of course.

Comment: Could you please explain why you suggest that "Mine" is correct.  That would make a much better answer.